# Update field based on array?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have created an array using this

```
import itertools

print list(itertools.permutations('123', 3))
```

this gives the result of

```
[('1', '2', '3'), ('1', '3', '2'), ('2', '1', '3'), ('2', '3', '1'), ('3', '1', '2'), ('3', '2', '1')]
```

I have a table looks like this

[image]

I want the array goes to each row something would look like this

[image]

What technique should I use?

(I transpose the array by the way and I may be able to export the array in CSV and join the two - but I dont want to do that)

----- updated---

based on Richard Morgan's comment
i tried to write this in the console

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor("featureclass", "c*")

for row in rows:
    row = [int(x[i]) for x in itertools.permutations('123', 3)]
    rows.updateRow(row)
```

and obviously it didn't work.

what magic do i need.. to fix this

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  Coding questions are expected to contain code.  I suggest you start with the documentation for `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` and organize your solution about that.  If you get stuck, update this question with your code and a *complete* description of your environment (ArcGIS release and OS)

Comment: If you use a loop for each FID, an UpdateCursor, and only include the c-fields, setting the row to `row = [int(x[i]) for x in itertools.permutations('123', 3)]` might work.  Given making a lot of assumptions.

Comment: i dont wanna bother you though.. could you please write entire code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screen shots you can do this while using Richards suggestion.  This assumes the datatype for the fields is a string, you can cast to integer if needed.

```
import arcpy
import itertools
a = list(itertools.permutations('123', 3))
wc = 'FID <> 0'
# fc is the full path to your feature class
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6'], wc)
idx = 0
for row in cursor:
    row = [x[idx] for x in a]
    cursor.updateRow(row)
    idx += 1
del cursor
```

Comment: nothing really happens to my shapefile ... :(

Comment: i copied and pasted your code to arcmap python console
 and it doesn't return nothing :@

Comment: actually it works!!! my korean character was the issue !!